# Weird reflection in final render

Tags: reflection

I've been going through the blender guru's 2.8 neon tutorial, and the result was looking alright, but in the final render a weird reflection appeared.

[image]

My brick texture is nonreflective, but this doesn't even seem like a normal reflection regardless. Even weirder, the reflection does not show up in the rendered view of the viewport, so I had no idea this was going to happen.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like an object than a reflection to me, my guess without seeing your file is that you have an object hidden in viewport yet set to visible in the render. [image]